# Enable "Save and Send Update" button for profiles

Tags: event

How to enable "Save and Send Update" button for custom profiles?

When I create event as system admin it is visible but for custom profiles it is not visible.

Comment: Where have you put this button? On a standard page layout? On a Visualforce page?

Comment: see https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2MXAAY for some ideas

Comment: @AmberNeillBoaz This button is standard button which we can not remove it and it is also not visible in pagelayout.